# Get the distinct count of values from a table with multiple where clauses

Tags: sql

My table structure is this

```
id   last_mod_dt     nr     is_u     is_rog     is_ror    is_unv
1       x            uuid1   1         1          1         0
2       y            uuid1   1         0          1         1
3       z            uuid2   1         1          1         1
```

I want the count of rows with:

1. `is_ror=1 or is_rog =1`
2. `is_u=1`
3. `is_unv=1`

All in a single query. Is it possible?

The problem I am facing is that there can be same values for nr as is the case in the table above.

Comment: Can you post the result you want to get?

Comment: which database are you using? mysql? oracle? please post a comment or edit your question or add the appropriate tag

Answer (score 1):

Case statments provide mondo flexibility...

```
SELECT
  sum(case
        when is_ror = 1 or is_rog = 1 then 1
        else 0
      end) FirstCount
 ,sum(case
        when is_u = 1 then 1
        else 0
      end) SecondCount
 ,sum(case
        when is_unv = 1 then 1
        else 0
      end) ThirdCount
 from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty simple if "all in a single query" does not disqualify subselects;

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nr) FROM table1 WHERE is_ror=1 OR is_rog=1) cnt_ror_reg,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nr) FROM table1 WHERE is_u=1) cnt_u,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT nr) FROM table1 WHERE is_unv=1) cnt_unv;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use union to get multiple results e.g.

select count(*) from table with is_ror=1 or is_rog =1
union
select count(*) from table with is_u=1
union
select count(*) from table with is_unv=1

Then the result set will contain three rows each with one of the counts.

Answer (score 0):

how about something like

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(is_u > 0 AND is_rog > 0, 1, 0)) AS count_something,
    ... 
from table
group by nr
```

I think it will do the trick

I am of course not sure what you want exactly, but I believe you can use the logic to produce your desired result.

Comment: @Bohemian if I see correct there is a column called "nr" with values uuid1 and uuid2